# angular.js Assert error throw async

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, assert, throw

I'm testing an `angular.js` app using `karma` with `sinon-chai`. I need to test a code like this:

```
var sync = function() {
  async.then(function() {
    // success
  }, function() {
    throw Error('foo');
  });
}
```

`sync` is the function I want to test. `async` is a function returning a `$q` promise I want to test it fails throwing an error.

My ideal test suit:

```
describe('unit', function() {
  it('should throw an error', function() {
    expect(function() {
      return sync();
    }).to.throw(Error, 'foo');
  })
});
```

But, it fails at `afterEach()` because the error is thrown on `$digest`.

How can I achieve this test?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get this working?